# Replace don't works correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple code where I receive data from database:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tmpDatosModulos.Rows)
{
    tmpBSCID += row["ModuloURL"].ToString();
    tmpBSCID.Replace("../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=", "");

}
Convert.ToInt32(tmpBSCID);
```

First `tmpBSCID` receive value like: `../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=21` now I want to replace it to drop all this part: `../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=` and get only last digits after `=`, but when I debug and it pass Replace instrucion it return all value: `../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=21` instead of `21`. Why it occurs? Regards

Comment: Strings are immutable and hence all string methods return a new string instead of modifying the passed. So you have to asssign the returned string to the original variable. `tmpBSCID = tmpBSCID.Replace(...) `

Comment: Off Topic: I think that a better approach is instead of saying "don't work correctly" say "I don't understand how to use the Replace function"

Comment: He doesn't know what he doesn't know.  At a guess, if he knew his understanding of strings was flawed, he could have just looked that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tmpBSCID = tmpBSCID.Replace("../BSC/wf_BSC_Reporte.aspx?BSCID=", "");
```

Methods on .NET strings **do not** change the string, they return a new string.